# Event handler not fire when accordion menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

i use accordion menu from this site http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordionmenu-bullet.htm

but when i insert radiobuttonlist inside this menu the event handler of onselectedindexchanged not fired .
can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding/defining the event handler after you are finished adding all elements to the radiobuttonlist.

Comment: including the accordion widget

Comment: i fill radiobuttonlist dynamically and the event fired after adding all elements

Comment: are you triggering after they are all added and the change event has been linked to the radiobutton list?

Comment: i think the problem is in accordion menu not in the event as when i click in any radiobutton the page postback but the event not fire